# SQL Server : select columns from Table A and join a COUNT from Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to create a SQL query that I can retrieve all of the information in one database transaction rather than have to load part of it within my C# code, and then fire off a child repeater to get a count on the rest of it.

These are along the lines of the tables I am trying execute this query on.

Table A (this is the product catalogue)

```
ID : Product     : Description
-----------------------------------------------
1  : Apple       : This fruit grows on trees
2  : Cherry      : This fruit grows on a bush
```

Table B (this is the sales tracker)

```
ID : Sold
---------
1  : 15
1  : 10
2  : 13
1  :  8
2  :  5
```

My desired result from the query would be

```
ID : Title   : Description                : Sold (Count)
---------------------------------------------------------
1  : Apple   : This fruit grows on trees  : 33
2  : Cheery  : This fruit grows on a bush : 18
```

What have I got so far? I must admit I've tried so many ways of trying to achieve this, that this is what I currently have open which does not work.

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.Title, a.Description, 
    ISNULL(b.Sold, 0) AS SellCount
FROM 
    TableA a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(b.Sold), b.ID 
     FROM
         TableB b 
     WHERE
         b.ID = a.ID 
     GROUP BY
         b.Sold) AS b ON b.ID = a.ID
```

Fairly new to the more advanced queries in SQL Server and I would really appreciate any help and guidance. Let me know if I can be more descriptive with anything.

Comment: You almost had it. Just remove the where clause in the (select count...) derived table (to which you assigned the alias "b").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, a.Description, SUM(ISNULL(b.Sold,0)) as SellCount
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b On b.ID = a.ID 
Group By a.ID, a.Title, a.Description
```

Comment: Awesome, and just like that my problem has been solved and I have learnt a few things from this. Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One method is with a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
      a.ID
    , a.Title
    , a.Description
    , (SELECT SUM(b.Sold) FROM TableB b WHERE b.ID = a.ID)
FROM TableA a;
```